# What kind of card-game questions are appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

I'm a particular fan of cards and card games.  What kinds of card-related questions do people think are emblematic of this site?

I had a question about card games come into question of being on-topic, but I"m not petitioning for it.  I'd just like to hear what kinds of card questions intrigue people here

- layouts and rules
- combinatoric strategies
- etc

Comment: This discussion was prompted by the question [Is there any card game with rules that dictate the replacement of cards on the table?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/453/is-there-any-card-game-with-rules-that-dictate-the-replacement-of-cards-on-the-t)

Answer (score 6):

We already have another StackExchange site for card games: [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/). Questions about card games should probably go there (not because questions can't be on-topic on multiple sites, because they can, but because card games are *games*, and this site is about puzzles).

Now, there are puzzles that involve cards. Questions like that should of course be on-topic here. There was another meta post where we discussed "solitaire" card games (there are multiple kinds) and how those tend to be more puzzle than game. I agree with this stance in general.

I think the general test for whether you should post a card-related question to Puzzling.SE should be "is this a puzzle or a game?" If it's a puzzle, post it here. If it's a game, it's not on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently a mod on BCG and would like to throw in a few thoughts from my perspective.

"Game recommendation" questions are a difficult topic on BCG, and there is no clear consensus on whether those should be allowed on BCG or not.

The particular question we're talking about here is not clear either, but personally, I would argue that due to its specific features it should rather be fine. Thus, I recommend moving it over.

Seen the other way around: It is quite likely more on topic at BCG than here, if I understand this correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what would make https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/453/is-there-any-card-game-with-rules-that-dictate-the-replacement-of-cards-on-the-t on-topic. Some puzzles can involve playing cards, but this question is solely about a game. While some puzzles can be played as single-player games (card solitaire games, Sokoban, etc.), I don't see how designing a card game meets any reasonable definition of “puzzle”.

Comment: Yes, this thread refines the scope of 'puzzles' for any who are considering different things.  The 'puzzle' dimension behind my question is not well represented, and that question warrants moving, or closing here.